# Insert data from VB.net to Access DB

Tags: database, vb.net, ms-access

In the following code, I'm trying to insert data to access DB and when I run it, nothing happens!!

```
Dim dbProvider = "PROVIDER=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;"
Dim dbSource = "Data Source= C:\Users\project\restDB.accdb"

Dim sql = "INSERT INTO Customer (ID, name, Phone, address) VALUES (@p1,@p2,@p3,@p4)"

Using con = New OleDb.OleDbConnection(dbProvider & dbSource)
    Using cmd = New OleDb.OleDbCommand(Sql, con)
        con.Open()
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", TextBox2.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p2", TextBox1.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p3", TextBox3.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p4", TextBox4.Text)
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End Using
End Using
```

Can someone help please!

Comment: Name is a [reserved word](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/286335) escape it with brackets: `[Name]`...and if ID is a number, you are passing text.  An exception is probably getting swallowed somewhere/somehow, you might add a Try/Catch just to debug and get error info.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with the provider

```
dbProvider = "PROVIDER=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;"
```